# How to detect from main UI thread that Parse's query.findInBackground has finished and returned data?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, parse-platform

In the function below, I am using `findInBackground` to get data from Parse. Since this function is running **in background**, how do I notify the main UI Thread when data is ready so that I can hide the progress loading spinner and actually show this data?

The reason for using `findInBackground` and not `find()` is because I don't want the main UI to freeze up when the fetch from the Parse Server is happening.

```
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Student");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject o : list) {
                Student s = new Student();
                s.setObjectId(o.getObjectId());
                s.setFirstName(o.getString("FirstName"));
                s.setSurname(o.getString("Surname"));
                s.setDOB(o.getString("DOB"));
                s.setInstructor(o.getBoolean("Instructor"));
                studentList.add(s);
            }
            // studentList is full here
        } else {

        }
        // studentList is full here too
    }

});
// studentList is empty here
return studentList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood. The network call `findInBackground` is done in the background, true. But `done` is called on the main thread. Therefore, any changes you make to the ui can be done there without problems. I dismiss spinners in my `done` callbacks all the time.

Looking through Parse.com source code; the `findInBackground()` calls this line:

```
 ParseTaskUtils.callbackOnMainThreadAsync(task, callback);
```

That tells me the callback is on the main thread. To be sure, I looked inside `ParseTaskUtils`. Sure enough, on line ~107, it switches back to the main thread to notify with results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great example of the Observer pattern with java interfaces:

http://javatechig.com/design-patterns/observer-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: But how do I know from the main thread that `done` is over. The control goes back to the main thread even before `done` is executed because it happens in background since it is inside the `findInBackground`

Comment: done is not "inside" the findInBackground, you pass a new FindCallback as an anonymous class.  This means that whenever it finishes whatever it is doing in the background it will execute that code.  So, that is why returning the studentList array isn't working.  I recommend doing anything you are going to do with that arrayList right in the done method.  cheers

Comment: This function is a separate class than my main activity. So how would I get a notification in the main activity? Do I have to use shared preferences or eventbus or something like that?

Comment: Is this function in an activity? If so, you could try the startActivityForResult, here's the documentation on that: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Otherwise you may use an interface that notifies your activity when you got a studentList

Comment: I think the interface is the answer I am looking for. Not sure how to implement an interface, something to learn I guess

Comment: I will provide an example in an answer